# Change only numbers' font

Tags: math-mode

I am writing math notes and use the `newtxmath` package because I like its epsilon symbol but I just want to change its numbers' font (0123456789) to that of package `amsmath`'s. How can I do it?
Currently I'm using `newtxmath` numbers which look like this:

[image]

I want to change them to look like the following:

[image]

Comment: `amsmath` alone doesn't change your number font. Do you by chance mean the Computer Modern font? A minimal example and the engine you use would help us suggest the best approach for this (in pdfTeX the approach will most likely be very different from the one in LuaTeX or XeTeX).

Comment: If you use LuaTeX or XeTeX you could use `unicode-math` and its `range` key. In pdfTeX things would be a bit more complicated I'm afraid.

Comment: The engine is Xe/LuaTeX, how about to use {amsfonts} or {amssymb}? In fact I don't know the difference between {amsmath}, {amsfonts} and {amssymb}. Previously I used {XITS Math} but I feel {newtxmath} and {XITS Math} can't be used at the same time, cause {unicode-math} doesn't support {newtxmath} Thanks

Comment: @Skillmon I want to keep {newtxmath}'s epsilon symbol and unicode-math and newtxmath can't be used same time. Thanks

Comment: @Ben Why not simply use both `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`? Computer Modern for text and `newtxmath` for symbols is not the best mix.

Comment: @egreg perfect, you are correct, use both `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` can match my requirement. I am newbie and don't know exact the difference or relationship between some packages. Thanks a lot